# How to get redis key value with class function and init file

Tags: php, redis

In my project, I use redis.

And I have a init file including ip port and port, so class Datasource is used for analying init file and connecting redis.

Here is class Datasource.php code with function getRedis() in it:

```
namespace common;

class Datasource {

public function __construct() {}

public static function getRedis($config_name = NULL, $server_region = 'default') {

    global $config;
    $redis_config = $config['redis'][$config_name];

    if ($config_name && $redis_config && $server_region) {
        $this->_config_name = $config_name;
        $this->_redis_config = $redis_config;
        $this->_server_region = $server_region;

        try {
            $this->_redis = new \Redis();
            $this->_redis->connect($this->_redis_config[$server_region]['host'], $this->_redis_config[$server_region]['port']);
            if($this->_redis_config[$server_region]['password'] && !$this->_redis->auth($this->_redis_config[$server_region]['password'])) {
                $this->_redis = null;
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->_redis = null;
        }
    } else {
        $this->_redis = null;
    }

    return self::$this->_redis;
   }
 }// end of class Datasource
```

Here is init file code of redis.ini.php

```
<?php
 $config['redis']['instance1'] = array(
'default' => array(
    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
    'port' => '6379',
    'timeout' => 5,
    'pconnect' => 1,
    'password' => '',
  )
);
 $config['redis']['instance2'] = array(
'default' => array(
    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
    'port' => '6379',
    'timeout' => 5,
    'pconnect' => 1,
    'password' => '',
    )
  );
```

Now I want to get xie value which is in redis, Here is my html code:

```
<body style="height:100%" >
<?php 
include "o1ws1v/class/common/Datasource.php";
include 'o1ws1v/conf/redis.ini.php';
$redis_obj = common\Datasource::getRedis('instance1');

$value = $redis_obj->get("xie");
echo "get key xie is:".$value."\n";

?>
</body>
```

Actually, key xie should be zuo. The corrent result is a line : "get key xie is:zuo"

But it showed nothing, Who can help me?

Comment: Where `xie` value is set to `zuo`?

Comment: In my redis server, I have defined xie  value. and in client line, I can get xie successfully and get zuo return value

Comment: Do `var_dump($redis_obj)`. Is it NULL?

Comment: @HtmHell, I used  " echo var_dump($redis_obj);", it is nothing

Comment: No echo. Just `var_dump($redis_obj);` right after `$redis_obj = common\Datas...`

Comment: @HtmHell, also nothing

Comment: @stack Did you take a look at my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You use `$this` in a static method, and you can't. Additionaly, you catch all Exceptions while connecting to Redis, so you can't know why it wasn't unsuccessful. You need to do two things:

1. Turning on PHP errors (for development only of course)
2. Don't catch the Exceptions while connecting, and if you do - then log / keep the Exception's message.

Try something like this:

```
<?php

namespace common;

class Datasource
{
    private static $_redis, $_config_name, $_redis_config, $_server_region;

    public static function getRedis($config_name = NULL, $server_region = 'default')
    {
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        ini_set("display_errors", true);

        global $config;

        $redis_config = $config['redis'][$config_name];

        if (!$config_name || !$redis_config || !$server_region) {
            throw new \Exception('$config_name or $redis_config or $server_region is not set');
        }

        if (!$redis_config[$server_region]['password']) {
            throw new \Exception('Redis password is not set');
        }

        self::$_config_name = $config_name;
        self::$_redis_config = $redis_config;
        self::$_server_region = $server_region;

        self::$_redis = new \Redis();

        self::$_redis->connect(self::$_redis_config[$server_region]['host'], self::$_redis_config[$server_region]['port']);

        if (!self::$_redis->auth(self::$_redis_config[$server_region]['password'])) {
            throw new \Exception("Can't login to Redis. Check password");
        }

        return self::$_redis;
    }
}
```

And the error displaying code is obviously not belong here, it's just for you to see if there are any errors temporarly.

Also, I would add a condition to see if Redis is already set, then return the connection. Otherwise you will make another connection every time you call `getRedis` method. Something like this:

```
public static function getRedis(...)
{
    if (!self::$_redis) {
        ...
    }

    return self::$_redis;
}
```